# Recursion in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cakephp, recursion

Coming from a CakePHP background, now working with ASP.NET, I'm struggling to find an equivalent feature in the model that was called Recursion in CakePHP.

For example, in a blog app, posts have authors. In Cake if I just wanted to retrieve the Post, and not the related entities, I'd set recursive to 0, and the model would only return that entity. If I set it to 1, it would bring back first level related entities too, so the authors name etc.

I'm looking for a similar function in ASP.NET's model, but can't seem to find anything similar, and keep getting reference loops on my API for example, Post, Author, Author's Posts, Post's Authors, and so on.

How do I limit the depth of recursion in ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you talking about an Web API application?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? There is Include method that we used for eager loading. More info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Web API and an MVC both using a shared model. Using EF yes.

Answer (score 5):

In Entity Framework this concept is known as Eager Loading.

Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method. For example, the queries below will load blogs and all the posts related to each blog.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blogs and its related posts 
    var blog1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    // Load all blogs and related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blogs2 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include("Posts") 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blog and its related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blog2 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include("Posts") 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Note that Include is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace so make sure you are using that namespace.

For more information refer this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. I take it there is no in-built in recursion property that can blanket all models then? Also, is the above code for the controller or model?

Comment: Well it is actually built-in into EF but optional in the form of explicitly loading (eager loading). This pattern ensure you do not load data from DB that you won't need. Fetching the data from DB is a concern often separated into a service layer and achieved using patterns like repository/generic repository, etc. For a reference check Sharp Architecture https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/tree/master/Solutions.

Comment: Explicitly including just the relationships you need is *far* better. Each relationship you eagerly load requires a separate join and joins are *slow*. Whoever decided in the development of CakePHP every single relationship should be loaded, all or none, is a bloody moron. I've never even seen that before. Even other frameworks like RoR and Django make you explicitly pull the relationships you want. Kiss that particular piece of trash functionality good bye and move on.

Comment: Also, EF lets you include N-depth relationships as well. For example, you could use `context.Blogs.Include("Posts.Comments")` to join both posts and comments for each of those posts at once.